# An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, libv8

I'm getting a cyclic error here:

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /path/to/website/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/cache/libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'` succeeds before bundling.

$ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'

Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:15931: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
Parsing documentation for libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14
Done installing documentation for libv8 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

$ bundle install --path vendor/cache
... many lines here ...
Using koala (1.10.1) 

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /path/to/website/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/cache/libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any suggestions?

==== UPDATE

I tried deleting all cache data with `rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/cache/` and now `bundle install --path vendor/cache` gives me:

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /path/to/website/vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/cache/libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 62):

For MacOS Catalina, Big Sur, and Monterey:

```
brew install v8@3.15
bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
bundle config build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8@3.15)
bundle
```

(update version numbers as needed)

Comment: Thanks, it works for Catalina when all the previous solutions failed.

Comment: I'm (newly) on Catalina, myself.

Comment: Thanks for MACOS solution!

Comment: Thank you! I followed other instructions that executes gem install (i.e. gem install libv8 -v 'YOUR_VERSION' -- --with-system-v8 and gem install therubyracer -v 'YOUR_VERSION' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15) and setting the bundle config build is key.

Comment: `bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8` solved a problem in Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: thank you so much. I've been facing this issue for a while and tried many things and finally found your answer. It helped in Big sur.

Answer (score 31):

Facing the same issue, install gem with system preferences worked for me

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7' -- --with-system-v8
```

Comment: What does `--with-system-v8` do ? @S.D

Comment: I had to do this after upgrading to macos Bigsur

Answer (score 15):

Usually the solution for this is updating libv8 to the latest version:

`bundle update libv8`

Comment: This is the only one that did it for me

Answer (score 11):

Run the following bundle config command then run bundle again

```
bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
```

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command than run the bundle install again.

```
rm ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-linux.gem
```